# Superset: Predefined shift times for users on the dashboard

Tags: time, range, apache-superset

I will define three fix time ranges filters for the users.
From 06 AM to 02 PM,
from 02 PM to 10 PM and
from 10 PM to 06 AM.
The user select only the date, but the hours range should select by a list item.

Is there a solution to this or a concept that I could pursue?

With the normal time range filter, the user has to make too many clicks, if he wants to evaluate the three times.